# Matching means and standard deviation

Tags: bayesian

People use simple mean and standard deviation marching all the time. I don't know the correct term for it - but it involves subtracting one datasets mean and then dividing by its standard deviation and then adding another datasets mean to it and multiplying through by the new data's standard deviation.

This allows one gaussIan to approximate the profile of another - is this an example of bayesian updating?  My question is a follows - can other distributions be treated the same way. For example the poisson distribution, can anything be done to match one datasets profile to another using only the distributions shape and rate info ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a normal distribution *N* with mean *m* and standard deviation *s*. Now you divide *N*'s mean by *m* and its standard deviation by *s*. This yields a normal distribution with mean 0 (*m* - *m* = 0) and standard deviation of 1 (*s* / *s* = 1).

Now you add a new value *x* and multiply a new standard deviation *y*. What you will get is a new distribution with mean *x* (0 + *x* = *x*) and standard deviation *y* (1 * *y* = *y*).

Can this be applied to other distributions? Yes, of course. You just need to manipulate the distribution's parameters accordingly.

The poisson distribution, for example, is defined by the *rate*. If you have a distribution *P* with rate *r*, you can divide the rate by *r* and multiply it with *z* to get a new poisson distribution with rate *z*.

It's not clear exactly where you want to apply this. In the examples above, you only exchange one parameter for another - that could be done directly. Where this kind of thing can come in handy is if these parameters are themselves aggregates of multiple underlying base values.

Let's say you have a poisson distribution with a rate parameter that is the sum of thousands of individual base values. You may not have a record of every value that went into the current rate. But now, you learn that a base value that you would have estimated to be *x* (e.g. using an old model) is actually *y*, you can update your rate even though you don't have access to all the other values that make up your rate.